# Repeating Form Fields In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which is submitting data to 2 separate models.

The model SalesItem belongs to Sale. A Sale can have many SalesItems.

I know I need to get the repeating fields into an array, but I'm not entirely sure how I should go about doing that. I though I had the right idea, but my controller isn't catching the array as the variable I was trying to set it up as.

Can see relevant code here: http://laravel.io/bin/Qzk24

All help is greatly appreciated!

```
/*** Sale Model  ***/
    class Sale extends \Eloquent {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function salesItem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SalesItem');
    }

    }

/*** SalesItem Model ***/
    class SalesItem extends \Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'SalesItems';

    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Sale');
    }
    }

/**** SalesController@store ****/
    public function store()
    {
        $sale = new Sale();
        if(Auth::user()){
            $userID = Auth::user()->id;
            $sale->user_id = $userID;
        }
        $sale->invoice_number = Input::get('invoice_number');
        $sale->name_of_purchaser = Input::get('name_of_purchaser');
        $sale->date_of_sale = Input::get('date_of_sale');


        // For each saleItem that exists
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            //Create new salesitem
            $saleItem = new SalesItem();
            //Save attributes 
            $saleItem->product_id = $item['equipment'];
            $saleItem->selling_price = $item['selling_price'];
            $saleItem->serial_number = $item['serial_number'];
            $saleItem->save();

            //associate with the sale
            $sale->salesItem()->associate($salesItem);
        }
        $sale->save();

        return "Sale Saved";
    }

/**** sales/create.blade.php *****/
     {{ Form::open(array('action'=>'SalesController@store')) }}
    <ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('invoice_number','Dealer Invoice Number:')}}
        {{ Form::text('invoice_number')}}
        {{ $errors->first('invoice_number','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('name_of_purchaser','Name of Purchaser:')}}
        {{ Form::text('name_of_purchaser')}}
        {{ $errors->first('name_of_purchaser','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::label('date_of_sale','Date of Sale:')}}
        {{ Form::text('date_of_sale')}}
        {{ $errors->first('date_of_sale','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2> Sale Items </h2>
            <ul class="repeatable"> 

                <li>
                    {{ Form::label('items[0][equipment]','Equipment:')}}
                    {{ Form::text('equipment[0]', Input::get('equipment'), array('class' => 'form-control clone'))}}
                    {{ $errors->first('equipment','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
                </li>

                <li>
                    {{ Form::label('selling_price[0]','Selling Price:')}}
                    {{ Form::text('selling_price[0]', Input::get('selling_price'), array('class'=>'form-control clone'))}}
                    {{ $errors->first('selling_price','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
                </li>

                <li>
                    {{ Form::label('serial_number[0]','Serial Number:')}}
                    {{ Form::text('serial_number[0]', Input::get('serial_number'), array('class'=>'form-control clone'))}}
                    {{ $errors->first('serial_number','<small class="error">:message</small>')}}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button href="#" class="add" rel=".clone"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Item</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::submit($buttonText) }}
    </li>
    </ul>
    {{ Form::close(); }}


/**** Getting this error Undefined variable: items 
 * /app/controllers/SalesController.php
****/
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question, it's really not clear.

Comment: Also post the relevant code here.

Comment: Basically I need to know how to get my store function to iterate over multiple instances of fields relating to the SalesItems Model. Updated question to include code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a few errors in your code, but I'll try to give you a direction..

Replace the input fields with something like this:

```
{{ Form::text('items[0]["equipment"]', array('class' => 'form-control clone'))}} 
.... 
{{ Form::text('items[0]["selling_price"]', array('class' => 'form-control clone'))}}
....
```

Grab the items using `$items = Input::get('items');` (btw this is the point where php threw an error: you never got the $items from the request)

Iterate over the items array and add every single one of it to your Sale model..